# Is it possible to get PdfEdit running on Ubuntu 12.10 using qt3to4?

Tags: qt, make, qt3

[PdfEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDFedit) is pretty much the only FOSS low-level PDF-editing tool out there. It's pretty useful, and pretty recent since it's updated in 2012.

However, it's a shame that packages are nowhere to be found, and I cannot get it to compile from [the source code](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfedit/) on recent distro's.

Aparently, this software uses an ancient form of `Qt` called `Qt3`. In order to build `Qt3` apps on `Qt4` systems, there is this library called `libqt4-qt3support` and this tool called `qt3to4` in the package `libqt4-dev-bin`. The idea is to convert the source code and compile the source with qt3-support.

I know nothing about `Qt`, but the basic idea is this, while in the root directory of the project.

Convert the `Qt3` source to `Qt4`:

```
qt3to4 -alwaysOverwrite ./src/gui/*
```

Remove the `Qt3` check from `configure` by commenting the check out:

```
nano ./configure

#       isqmake3=`$testbin --version 2>&1 | grep '3\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*'`
#       if test -z "$isqmake3"
#       then
#               testbin=""
#       fi
```

Configure:

```
./configure
```

Make:

```
make && sudo make install
```

But make quits with an error:

```
...
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/pdfedit/src'
make: *** [source] Error 2
```

So, does anyone have the knowledge to make this work? It would be awesome. We can then apply this to other packages as well. And we can finally answer [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216396/how-do-i-install-pdfedit-on-ubuntu-12-10). :)

Comment: I posted my solution here, which is basically reloading the QT3 libraries required to run pdfedit instead of trying to convert it to run using qt4 libraries: http://askubuntu.com/a/254070/130399

Hopefully it helps you or someone searching for this question.

Comment: Could you copy your answer here preceded by that link to your original post? It's the closest thing to an acceptable answer, and according to the PdfEdit bugtracker, converting `Qt3` to `Qt4` seems to take so long, it probably is not as easy as I thought. Funny detail: The Windows version is now `Qt4`.