# Is there any open-source way to make a static from a dynamic executable with no source code availability?

Tags: compiling, libraries, shared-library

Let me explain the problem with an example. I use some old program in my day to day work, like for example [xfig](http://www.xfig.org/) and [pdfedit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfedit/).

Now, these programs are quite old and not updated too often; my fear is that one day or the other they will not work anymore for lack of some library or some incompatible update.

If the program is easy to compile *now*, on a running system, the solution is handy: try to hack a bit the source and compile it statically --- the resulting executable will be big and not so efficient, but it will work for the foreseeable future(1). This seem to be the case for `xfig` and I will try it as soon as possible.

But, for example, `pdfedit` depends on Qt3, and setting up a system to compile it is quite complex at this time. Fortunately [it can be run](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216396/how-do-i-install-pdfedit) right now, thanks to the fact that the library it needs do not conflict with anything. But this can change in the future, so I would like to solve this problem:

**How can can I make a static binary (or similar thing) if I have a dynamic one and all the libraries, but no source code, on Ubuntu?**

I searched around. One possibility is [statifier](http://statifier.sourceforge.net/)(2), but  it has a lot of [problems with the address randomization](http://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2009/105/Ermine-vs.-Statifier), so it's a no-no. The non-free version, [Ermine](http://www.magicermine.com/products.html), seems to work, but I would really prefer an open source option.

Another possibility is to use docker or a similar packaging system. But all the [tutorial I found are quite RedHat-oriented](https://blog.openshift.com/day-21-docker-the-missing-tutorial/); and, honestly, quite complex to follow.

---

*Footnotes*:

(1) is not so crazy. I use a [static ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/) for example, works ok and without any compatibility problems...

(2) to compile `statifier`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498237/compile-program-for-32bit-on-64bit-linux-os-causes-fatal-error

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can solve your problem in another and more simple way:

Use `ldd` on your executable to see the linked libraries, for example:

```
$ ldd /bin/bash
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffb2fd4000)
libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007fac9ef91000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fac9ed8d000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fac9e9c6000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fac9f1e1000)
```

Then collect all the libraries in a folder and set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable before running your program to point at this folder:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/my_program/lib" /opt/my_program/start
```

Alternatively you can add an entry for the lib folder to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`. But that would apply the change systemwide.

Comment: This is a good idea --- although I would really like to find a way to package all this into an executable; this solution can be affected by changes in the loader (although I hope no one will do such a thing in non-backward compatible way). Will award the bounty if no better solutions arise --- thanks.

Comment: Well you could add this to a little installation script and link it to the local path. I like this solution, could have used it a time back.

Comment: @Klaus, `linux-vdso.so.1`  is nowhere to be seen, I suppose it's in the kernel, correct?

Comment: Yes. From `man 7 vdso`: "The "vDSO" (virtual dynamic shared object) is a small shared library that the kernel automatically maps into the address space of all user-space applications."

Comment: Although this is not *strictly* an answer to the question, it is a reasonable workaround. Thanks.

Comment: on osx, `otool -L` instead of `ldd`, btw.

Comment: This is not a robust solution. The linked libraries may also be dynamic and depend on other libraries. Bundling the direct dependencies will only gather one layer and may appear to work initially but then fail when deployed somewhere where one of the dependent libraries is missing its dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Opensource [mkblob](https://github.com/sigurd-dev/mkblob) can make a new binary executable which includes all the dependencies your program needs and you will be able to distribute it to other (also later) distributions than the one it was compiled on. It works a little like Statifier and Ermine which was mentioned.

Comment: Hi! Seems nice, but I haven't been able to use it on Ubuntu. Have you any hint?

Comment: There is a precompiled binary and deb/rpm in https://github.com/sigurd-dev/mkblob/tree/master/binary_X86_64

Also it seems I could compile it in Ubuntu 18.04 with the makeall_el8.sh.

Comment: Thanks --- yes, I installed the .deb but it does not seems to work with a couple of binaries I checked... I mean, the binary runs, but it does not succeed in creating a static binary with some programs. Well, time for another question! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote [packelf.sh](https://github.com/oufm/packelf/blob/master/packelf.sh) based on Klaus D's idea.

You can use it like this:

```
~ # packelf.sh `which perf` /root/perf
~ # /root/perf --version
perf version 3.10.0-1160.49.1.el7.x86_64.debug
```

[packelf.sh](https://github.com/oufm/packelf/blob/master/packelf.sh):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -eo pipefail

[ $# -lt 2 ] && {
    echo "usage: $0 <ELF_SRC_PATH> <DST_PATH> [ADDITIONAL_LIBS ...]"
    exit 1
}

src="$1"
dst="$2"
shift
shift

cat >"$dst" <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
tmp_dir="\$(mktemp -d)"
check_path="\$tmp_dir/__check_permission__"
trap 'rm -rf \$tmp_dir' 0 1 2 3 6
if ! (touch "\$check_path" && chmod +x "\$check_path" && [ -x "\$check_path" ]); then
    rm -rf "\$tmp_dir"
    tmp_dir="\$(TMPDIR="\$(pwd)" mktemp -d)"
fi
sed '1,/^#__END__$/d' "\$0" | tar -xz -C "\$tmp_dir"
"\$tmp_dir/LD_SO" --library-path "\$tmp_dir" "\$tmp_dir/PROGRAM" "\$@"
exit \$?
#__END__
EOF

libs="$(ldd "$src" | grep -F '/' | sed -E 's|[^/]*/([^ ]+).*?|/\1|')"
ld_so="$(echo "$libs" | grep -F '/ld-linux-')"
sed -E -i -e 's|PROGRAM|'"$(basename "$src")"'|' -e 's|LD_SO|'"$(basename "$ld_so")"'|' "$dst"
tar -czh --transform 's/.*\///g' "$src" $libs "$@" >>"$dst" 2> >(grep -v 'Removing leading' >&2)
chmod +x "$dst"
```

Comment: this create a bash script, with appended tgz. it will do ➀ shell, tar extract to tmp ➁  run tmp file. (on every time you execute it)

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion regarding [statifier](http://statifier.sourceforge.net/):

If address space layout randomization (ASLR) is causing it to fail you don't have to turn it off for the whole machine. You can turn it off just for that process:

```
$ setarch `uname -m` -R statified_pdfedit [args...]
```

It'll run that command with randomized layout disabled (no need to be root).

Comment: Wow, interesting. Now if I just could compile `statifier`...

Comment: Compiled and checked. `xfig_statified` still core dumps... a pity. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah, a pity. I'm wondering if it wouldn't be a 64bit issue, try running statifier on a 32bit setup maybe ?

Comment: Checked on a 32-bit machine, still core dumps.